# Im having problems printing a 2d array in a 3x3 format

Tags: arrays, c, file, multidimensional-array

I have the code running to extract 18 integers from a textfile, and to store 9 of the integers in one array and the remaining 9 in another. When I print it all out its fine, except its printing in rows of 2 rather than 3 and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  
  int count = 0;
  int matrixA [3][3];
  int matrixB [3][3];
  FILE *fptr;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  
   fptr = fopen("Matrices.txt","r");
    if(fptr == NULL){
      printf("Error! File cannot be opened");
      exit(1);
      }
  
    while( i < 3 && j < 3 && 2 == fscanf(fptr, "%d%d", &matrixA[i][j], &matrixB[i][j])){
      count++;
      printf("%d %d ", matrixA[i][j], matrixB[i][j]);
      //printf("count %d\n",count);
        if(count % 3){
          printf("\n");
        } 
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: You're just reading all the numbers into the same array elements and printing them as you go.  You're not filling the arrays... you don't even change the indices.

Comment: To fix `count`, declare and initialize it before the loop instead of inside it.  Right now you set it to `1` at the start of each pass.  And if you want to fill those matrices for real, you'll need to update `i` and `j` in the loop (one every pass, the other when you finish a row).

Comment: Also, I think the count condition checks it is not zero which is wrong.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The following code read 18 integer in couples and print them. For using 2d arrays in C you must write multiple loops (it is easier and more understandable too).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int count = 0;
  int matrixA [3][3];
  int matrixB [3][3];
  FILE *fptr;

  fptr = fopen("Matrices.txt","r");
  if (fptr == NULL){
    printf("Error! File cannot be opened");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (fscanf(fptr, "%d %d", &matrixA[i][j], &matrixB[i][j]) != 2) {
      return 0;
    }
    count++;
    printf("%d %d ", matrixA[i][j], matrixB[i][j]);
    if(count % 3 == 0){
      printf("\n");
    } 
    }
  }

  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

About conditions, when you write `if (count % 3)` means `if (count % 3 != 0)` which is wrong here.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: In the code, I tried to fix the issues that I mentioned. It reads 2d array with loop in loop and fixes the condition for printing 3 couples in row.